# Issue creating .Net 4.5.2 project in VS 2015. Seem to get vNext Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a problem when creating a project in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.

I am trying to create a .NET 4.5.2 project for parsing XML documents.

[image: Creating the Project]

After creating the project the structure looks like this

[image: Structure]

Which I believe is a vNext structure. New json style.

The real problem arises when I add a reference to XDocument via NuGet

[image: Build errors]

I tried poking around posts with similar issues but couldn't find one the wasn't trying to use/mix .NET 5.

I have tried doing a repair of my installation.

Comment: If you look at the project properties, is the Target Framework set to .Net Framework 4.5.2 or .net Framework 4 Client Profile?

Comment: Project properties look strange. I don't see the normal Build target. 
I have "Solution DNX SDK version: 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

I don't see "4.5.2" or "Framework 4" anywhere.

Configuration and Platform are both "N/A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class library template in the Web section is for the new .NET Core libraries. You will find the library template you are looking for under the Windows section.

[image]

Comment: Ah, you can tell it is Friday... I did not see the fact that he had selected a package template.

Comment: Didn't even realize I was in the web section! Thanks.